# Symlink all files in a directory with the entire directory tree

Tags: osx, symlink, ln

Right now I use this

```
ln -s /dir/* /dir2/
```

Which will symlink everything, but I have to go inside the `dir` and make a new directory because the folders are also symlinked (this is expected).

So here is what Im trying to achieve: Symlink all files, but when there is a folder, make a directory with the same name and symlink the files inside of that folder and inside that folder, etc.

Much like GNU `cp` with the `-al` flag, which I got by running `brew install coreutils`.

```
gcp -al /dir1/ dir2/
```

This does what I want except they are hard links and not symlinks.

Comment: `gcp -as` (only works with absolute paths though).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should separate the file handling from the directory handling. Make the directories first. In the GNU world:

```
cd /dir2
find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir {} \;
```

And then the symlinks:

```
find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ln -s -t /dir2 {} +
```

Comment: Drop `-maxdepth 1` since the copy should recurse. `mkdir {}` is wrong: you're attempting to create directories that already exist. You need to translate `/dir` into `/dir2` in the paths.